# Best practice of directly go to an url when using window.history

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I'm using `history.state` to navigate between my Javascript pages. All works well, except when I want to go to a page by entering an url like https://www.myapp.com/Main (Main is an excisting page in my app). Offcourse it can't find the **Main** folder because it doesn't excist.

My approach would be:

1. Configure my .htaccess file to rewrite pathnames to $_GET parameters in PHP
2. In the `<head>` or `<body>` (before any other script is loaded), translate the $_GET parameters to Javascript by doing something like `<script> var GET = <?php echo $_GET; ?> </script>`
3. Then navigate to the page in `window.onload`

Is there any other or better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is the question 'how should I deal with 404 errors'?

Comment: I want the /Main to redirect to the index.php and in my window.onload function I need to know that I must open the page (javascript plugin) **Main**

Comment: Don’t see any need to pass stuff along as GET parameters and then output it again … All this needs would be an _internal_ redirect to the index.php (no parameters), so that in the browser address bar it still reads `https://www.myapp.com/Main` - so your client-side JS can read the info it needs directly from `location.pathname`

Comment: @CBroe Something like this? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: Yeah, but maybe preceded by a RewriteCond that excludes physically existing files/folders from being rewritten - otherwise you won’t be able to serve static assets any more directly.

Comment: Thnx @Cbroe, works like a charm! I updated my question with the answer.

Comment: Great! You should make that an actual answer (you’re allowed to answer your own questions, where that’s applicable) though, that can then be accepted (and possibly upvoted.) If this question has an accepted answer, it can be linked as a duplicate for further, similar questions, whereas if you only edit your “success message” into the question, that would not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an *internal* redirect like this to redirect to index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

That way the browser address bar still reads `https://www.myapp.com/Main`. So the javascript can read the pathname from `location.pathname`